# Send data from intent to intend via i.putExtra

Tags: android, camera

I want to get the camera result in an activity which is started via tabhost.

Code StartActivity:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ListActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list").setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab_label_list),
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.list_tab))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

ListActivity (extends BaseActivity):

```
takeScreenshotButton.setText(getString(R.string.upload_screenshot_button_label));
    takeScreenshotButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/tmp")));
            i.putExtra("CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST", CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            i.putExtra("test", 2);
            OpenMatchActivity.this.getParent().getIntent().putExtra("test", 1);
            OpenMatchActivity.this.getParent().startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

I tried to send extra informations via putExtra.

But in ListActivity the extra info is not contained:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        String cam = extras.getString("CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST");
        String test = extras.getString("test");
       ...
    }
```

What can i do to get the value of the tab host activity within the tabhost activity?

Comment: you are missing `setResult(RESULT_OK,i)`.

Answer (score 1):

http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/two-way-communication-between-tabactivity-and-its-child-tabs/

this is what i searched for

```
 getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("tab");
```

And then you can get all properties.